# Some unknown marks: are they in Chinese? If not, what language is it? What do they mean?

Tags: character-identification

I have been given a nice set of small white tea set with bamboo motifs and some foreign oriental marks. There is no single English character. I spent the whole morning trying to draw these marks and see if I can find their meaning but no luck so far. Thanks in advance! Jane

[image: square mark with Chinese characters? It is underneath of 3 cups]

[image: Similar characters but not in square mark - it is underneath of tea pot with lid and other pot with no lid]

[image: Red small mark in circle - on each piece on top or side of them]

[image: THis mark is on 3 cups underneaths of them]

Answer (score 2):

in top picture set of characters looks like 1st column  鹏雅, 2nd column 精瓷, always top to bottom, anyhow googling  鹏雅精瓷 yields as 1st result zhidao.baidu.com with 鹏雅精瓷酒杯

picture below more clearly looks like 鹏祥

Comment: I will follow your recommendations - but from answer I understand that this indeed is Chinese, which helps massively ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @S.Rhee Actually, you could add some translations, too. I assume, Jane doesn't speak Chinese, so she could at least grasp what is printed on the items, Google Translation tends to be rather unreliable.

Comment: to get an idea of the meaning could enter 鹏雅精瓷into 小马词典: http://www.xiaoma.info/compound.php?cp=%E9%B9%8F%E9%9B%85%E7%B2%BE%E7%93%B7&fhz=%E9%B9%8F%E9%9B%85%E7%B2%BE%E7%93%B7

Comment: also note that characters written in lines sometimes are written from right to left, this may apply to the 2nd picture containing 鹏祥, since 祥 is an adjective  auspicious ； propitious ； lucky (as well as a surname) and 鹏 is a noun. Besides 祥鹏 Lucky Air is the name of an an airline company.

Comment: Thank you all for providing me with so many useful info! I am amazed by the capacity of this simple character 精 - it has so many meanings.. There is one red mark on those cups - I posted the photo of it earlier - are these any characters or rather decorative feature ? And how about the black strange mark - which looks like PI with dots - I don't think it is Chinese - but yet these all marks are on the same tea set - just some marked differently than others.. this is so intriguing :D

Comment: @Jane if the characters above and below the pi-with-dots are in the same orientation, then you have it upside down :) Above says 全 (quán) and below says 顺 (shùn) and if the pi-with-dots are in the same orientation, then it's not a character I know of.

Comment: Thank you ! This must then be some sort of logo I guess. I am stunned by the help I received from everyone - thank you for help in identifying these characters!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are truly Chinese. From top to bottom：

**鹏雅精瓷**： “精瓷” is a kind of chinaware, and “鹏雅” is the brand name, I think.

**鹏祥**：(the words from left to right) I think it is also the brand name of the plate/tea set.

**吉**：which means “lucky”. I think it is the Chinese character “吉” with a circle around it in the picture.

**金顺**：in the picture, the words are upside down with the logo(or some image) in the middle. I think it is also the brand name. “金” means “gold”, while “顺” means (everything goes)smoothly; without a hitch.

As far as I know, in the old times, in the bottom of chinaware, people will write the name of the year of that dynasty, like "大清雍正年制(Made during Yongzheng's ruling years of Great Qing Dynasty)". In the modern time, the chinaware tea set or wine set are tend to be written on the brand name or factory name on the bottom.

Correct me if I am wrong :)

Meanings are searched based on http://www.xiaoma.info/

Comment: Excellent supplementary answer willyang! Thank you for elaborating on the meanings and those up-side-down characters. You was wonderfully helpful Oh - and even if I wanted to I cannot 'correct' you because I am totally unfamiliar with chinaware, perhaps somebody else will  step in :D

Comment: @jane if this was helpful you should mark this answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

These are all brand names, I suppose.

As Chinese, I hate these...

If you are interested in chinas, remember that: **Thinner Is Better** (Some gorgeous chinas will let the light go through). And the best chinas in China are always produced in 景德镇.

**And notice if you found a bowl with "**朝****年制" on a high price, never buy it. They are forgery.**